# How to go to the outer do-while loop when the condition inside the inner do-while loop satisfies in php?

Tags: php

```
do // first do-while loop
{
    $sqlSeltime = "SELECT * FROM tbltime WHERE subtype = '$subtype' AND units = '$subunits' AND classtype = 'Lec' AND (time_value = '60' OR time_value = '90') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $sqlStoreTime = mysqli_query($connect, $sqlSeltime);
    $rowTime = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlStoreTime);
    $time_day = $rowTime["time_day"];
    $day_avail = $rowTime["day_avail"];
    $starting = $rowTime["start_time"];
    $ending = $rowTime["end_time"];

    $sqlSelRoom = "SELECT * FROM tblroom WHERE room_type = 'Lecture' and college = '$college' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ";
    $sqlStoreRoom = mysqli_query($connect, $sqlSelRoom);
    $rowRoom = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlStoreRoom);
    $room = $rowRoom["room"];


    if ($day_avail == 'M/F' || $day_avail == 'M/W/F' || $day_avail == 'W')
    {
        do // second do while loop
        {
            $selectinsection = "SELECT * FROM tblschedule WHERE year_level = '$year' AND section = '$section' AND college = '$college' AND ((day_lec = 'M/F' OR day_lab = 'M/F') OR (day_lec = 'M/W/F' OR day_lab = 'M/W/F') OR (day_lec = 'W' OR day_lab = 'W')) ";
            $resultinsection = mysqli_query($connect, $selectinsection);
            while($rowinsection = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultinsection))
            {
                $startminlecinsection [] = $rowinsection["start_timeminlec"];
                $endminlecinsection [] = $rowinsection["end_timeminlec"];
                $startmajlecinsection [] = $rowinsection["start_timemajlec"];
                $endmajlecinsection [] = $rowinsection["end_timemajlec"];
                $startmajlabinsection [] = $rowinsection["start_timemajlab"];
                $endmajlabinsection [] = $rowinsection["end_timemajlab"];
            }

            $startminlecsize = count($startminlecinsection);
            $endminlecsize = count($endminlecinsection);
            $startmajlabsize = count($startmajlecinsection);
            $endmajlabsize = count($endmajlecinsection);
            $startmajlecsize = count($startmajlabinsection);
            $endmajlecsize = count($endmajlabinsection);

            $startminlecinsection = array_values($startminlecinsection);
            $endminlecinsection = array_values($endminlecinsection);
            $startmajlecinsection = array_values($startmajlecinsection);
            $endmajlecinsection = array_values($endmajlecinsection);
            $startmajlabinsection = array_values($startmajlabinsection);
            $endmajlabinsection = array_values($endmajlabinsection);

            for($ctr = 0; $ctr <= ($startminlecsize - 1); $ctr++)
            {
                if (isBetween($startminlecinsection[$ctr], $endminlecinsection[$ctr], $starting, $ending) == 'FALSE' )
                {
                    $chk = 0;
                    break 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $chk = 1;
                }
            }

            for($ctr = 0; $ctr <= ($startmajlecsize - 1); $ctr++)
            {
                if (isBetween($startmajlecinsection[$ctr], $endmajlecinsection[$ctr], $starting, $ending) == 'FALSE' )
                {
                    $chk1 = 0;
                    break 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $chk1 = 1;
                }
            }

            for($ctr = 0; $ctr <= ($startmajlabsize -1); $ctr++)
            {
                if (isBetween($startmajlabinsection[$ctr], $endmajlabinsection[$ctr], $starting, $ending) == 'FALSE' )
                {
                    $chk2 = 0;
                    break 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $chk2 = 1;
                }
            }

            if($chk == 0 || $chk1 == 0 || $chk2 == 0)break; // if this is true the execution of the program should continue to the first do-while loop
        }
        while($chk == 0 || $chk1 == 0 || $chk2 == 0);
    }
    else
    {
    }
while(condition);
```

This is my code from my current project automated class scheduler. I have a function(); named isBetween - it used in checking for schedule conflicts. I had three for loop to check 3 schedules namely the schedule for minor subject, major lecture and major laboratory. when one of them returns '0' the process should start right to the first loop because the block of codes after the first do while loop is the one responsible in generating rooms, time of class and day. Now when a conflict occured the program should generate another time,day and room. and it is right after the first do-while loop.

Comment: You want to `break;` out of it

Comment: "If condition inside the _for_ loop returns true" — for loops don't work that way except you write something along the lines of `for(;condition;)` which is not so eloquent. You want to learn how to use the `if-statement`

Comment: add break; statement in if condition in case of condition true it will break inner loop and go to outer loop

Comment: @OluwafemiSule i tried but it doesn't work. I will post my code right after this comment for better understanding about my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `break;` to say exit the current loop.

```
do // this is the first do-while loop
{
    if(condition)
    {
        do // this is the second do-while loop
        {
            for(condition)
            {
                //do something
            }
            // if the process inside the for loop returns true the execution
            //   of the program should continue to the first do-while loop
            if ( condition == true ) {
                break;
            }
        }
        while(condition);
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
while(condition);
```

If you wanted to exit the `for()` loop straight away if a condition is met, you can use `break 2;` which exits 2 levels of loop.

```
do // this is the first do-while loop
{
    if(condition)
    {
        do // this is the second do-while loop
        {
            for(condition)
            {
                //do something
                if ( condition == true ) {
                    break 2; // Exit to outer loop
                }
            }
        }
        while(condition);
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
while(condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that `break` and `continue` are to different statements.

`break` is used to interupt a loop and continue the script, whereas `continue` skips one round in the loop, but does not interrupt it.

continue:

```
for(i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
 if(i == 3)
 {
  //if i is 3, just do nothing but go to i is 4.
  continue;
 }
 else
 {
  echo $i." Hello World.<br>";
 }
}

//1 Hello World
//2 Hello World
//4 Hello World
//5 Hello World
```

break:

```
for(i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
 if(i == 3)
 {
  //if i is 3, exit the loop
  break;
 }
 else
 {
  echo $i." Hello World.<br>";
 }
}

//1 Hello World
//2 Hello World
```